# Why are my stored entities using default values?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am saying

```
data := Thing {
    date:     time.Now().UnixNano()   
    name:     "foo",
    value:    5,
}
_, err := datastore.Put(c, datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "stuff", nil), &data)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
```

What is getting stored is `{0, "", 0}`.  I expect to see something like `{1366370653722376000, "foo", 5}`.  What am I doing wrong?

Note: I am using the dev appserver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must export the names you want to be visible outside your package. To achieve that you must use as its first letter any Unicode upper-case-class (which ASCII upper case letters are a subset), e.g. `Date` instead of `date`, `Name` instead of `name`, etc.

Without that the `datastore.Put` cannot "see" (using reflection) the fields.